# iTextSharp - Don't display page numbers if only one page

Tags: itext

I have a PDF generated using iTextSharp that displays a "Page 1/4" etc. thing in the footer. This all works fine and is implemented using a `PdfTemplate` that is set in the `OnEndPage()` method with the total number of pages added in the `OnCloseDocument()` method.

What I would like to do is remove this if there is only one page in the document. I've tried this in my `OnCloseDocument()` method, but it doesn't actually remove the template:

```
        public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            base.OnCloseDocument(writer, document);

            if (writer.PageNumber >= 3)
            {
                template.BeginText();
                template.SetFontAndSize(f_cn, CocService.footerFont.Size);
                template.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);
                template.ShowText("" + (writer.PageNumber - 1));
                template.EndText();
            }
            else
            {
                template.Reset();
            }
        }
```

Just for reference, here's the relevant code from the `OnEndPage()` method:

```
        public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            base.OnEndPage(writer, document);

            int pageN = writer.PageNumber;
            String text = "Page " + pageN.ToString() + "/";

            float len = f_cn.GetWidthPoint(text, CocService.footerFont.Size);
            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pageSize = document.PageSize;
            cb.SetRGBColorFill(100, 100, 100);
            cb.BeginText();
            cb.SetFontAndSize(f_cn, CocService.footerFont.Size);
            cb.SetTextMatrix(document.LeftMargin+520, pageSize.GetBottom(document.BottomMargin)+33);
            cb.ShowText(text);
            cb.EndText();
            cb.AddTemplate(template, document.LeftMargin + 520 + len, pageSize.GetBottom(document.BottomMargin)+33);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already writing text to the content stream in your `onEndPage()` method, and there's no way to remove that *after the fact* because that stream may already have been sent to the `OutputStream`.

The best way to avoid having any page numbers on a document if there's only one page, is to add page numbers in a second go. Take a look at the [TwoPasses](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=118) example, especially where it says "SECOND PASS". IMO, this is the most elegant way to solve your problem. Ask the `reader` for the number of pages. If it's 1, do nothing. If it's more, add *page X of Y*.

By the way: for the C# port of the examples, go to http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C06

Comment: This is a great answer, though not the one I ended up going with (see my own answer below). Elegance, as always, is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Error 404: C# example not found

Answer (score 4):

The solution I ended up going with was adding a separate `PdfTemplate` object to each page, then setting all the page numbers (or leaving them out altogether) in the `OnCloseDocument()` method. I thought this was pretty elegant too. Here's the essential code:

```
    // Inner class for dealing with the page numbering
    class CocPdfEventHelper : PdfPageEventHelper
    {
        List<PdfTemplate> pageNumberTemplates = new List<PdfTemplate>();

        public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            base.OnEndPage(writer, document);

            // Add a unique (empty) template for each page here
            PdfTemplate t = writer.DirectContent.CreateTemplate(180, 50);
            pageNumberTemplates.Add(t);
            writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(t, document.LeftMargin + 520, document.PageSize.GetBottom(document.BottomMargin) + 33);
        }

        public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            base.OnCloseDocument(writer, document);

            // Only bother if there is more than 1 page
            if (writer.PageNumber >= 3)
            {
                int count = 1;
                foreach (PdfTemplate template in pageNumberTemplates)
                {
                    template.BeginText();
                    template.SetFontAndSize(f_cn, CocService.footerFont.Size);
                    template.SetRGBColorFill(100, 100, 100);
                    template.SetTextMatrix(0,0);
                    template.ShowText("Page " + count + " of " + (writer.PageNumber - 1));
                    template.EndText();
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```